# Iterated integral $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x+y}$, $1≤x$, $0≤y≤\frac{1}{k}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble understanding the convergence and value of the iterated integral

$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x+y}$$ $0≤x$, $0≤y≤\frac{1}{x}$.

I've tried bounding the $1≤x$ to $1≤x≤k$ and then trying to calculate

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}}\int_1^k \frac{1}{x+y} dx dy$$ but this leads to messy logarithms, which don't seem like they can be solved. I think I need to consider the limit $k \rightarrow \infty$, but some of the terms do go to $\infty$, but then the integral isn't convergent.

Comment: For an arbitrary $y$, what is $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x+y}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}$ $\int_1^{k} \frac{dx}{x+y} = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} ln(k+y)-ln(1+y)=\infty$?

Comment: Yes. And if you then integrate over $y$ …

Comment: Why do you cut at $k$? If you don't, you have the simple $\int_0^{1/k} +\infty\,dy = +\infty$.

Comment: This is supposed to be convergent.

Comment: It isn't if the domain is $\{(x,y) : 1 \leqslant x, 0 \leqslant y \leqslant 1/k\}$. Can you precisely state the domain?

Comment: @DanielFischer $\int_0^{\frac{1}{k}}ln(k+y)=|_0^{\frac{1}{k}}(k+y)(ln(k+y)-(k+y)$ and the other integral is done the same way. This leads to $[(k+\frac{1}{k})ln(k+\frac{1}{k})-(k+\frac{1}{k})-(yln(y)-y)]-[(1+\frac{1}{k})ln(1+\frac{1}{k})-(1+\frac{1}{k})-((1+0)log(1)-(1+0))]$

Comment: @DanielFischer The domain is $x≥1, 0≤y≤\frac{1}{x}$ which I think becomes $1≤x≤k, 0≤y≤\frac{1}{k}$

Comment: Aha. That's an entirely different kettle of fish. Note that you can also describe that as $\{(x,y) : 0 \leqslant y \leqslant 1, 1 \leqslant x \leqslant 1/y\}$. In that form, you get something nicer when you integrate.

Comment: @DanielFischer Then one has to integrate $ln(\frac{1}{y}+y)$ which I don't know. Is this even defined for $y=0$

Comment: Ah, right, it's $\frac{1}{x}$ that gives an easy integral. Well, that at least gives you an easy proof of convergence. The value isn't so easy to come by, $\ln (1+ 1/x^2)$ isn't so nice to integrate either.

Comment: @DanielFischer So what is the domain?